# Expected number of times to roll a die until each face comes up the same number of times

Tags: probability, dice

What is the expected number of times to roll an ordinary $6$-sided die until each face comes up the same number of times?

This question is suggested by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3316404/how-many-times-will-you-have-to-roll-a-six-sided-die-until-you-see-each-number-o). JMoravitz suggested the reformulation given here, and Erick Wong commented that, since there is a positive probability that the event never occurs, the expected waiting time is infinite.

I have a calculation that purports to show the expected waiting time is finite, though I don't believe that.  My reaction when I read the linked question was "forever".  I need help finding the error, because I haven't been able to locate it.

In order for each face to come up an equal number of times, we have to make $6n$ rolls.  The probability that every face has come up $n$ times is$$
{{6n\choose n,n,n,n,n,n}\over6^{6n}}= {(6n)!\over(n!)^66^{6n}}
$$ so the expected number of rolls is bounded above by $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 6n{(6n)!\over(n!)^66^{6n}}\tag{1}
$$
I say "bounded above" because the summand in $(1)$ only take account of the probability that the event occurs after $6n$ rolls, and it should use the probability that the event *first* occurs after $6n$ rolls, which cannot be more.  Then by Stirling's approximation, $$
6n{(6n)!\over(n!)^66^{6n}}\sim 
6n{{(6n)^{6n}e^{-6n}\sqrt{12n\pi}}\over
{(n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2n\pi}})^6 6^{6n}}=6n{\sqrt{12n\pi}\over{(2n\pi)^3}}=O(n^{-3/2}),
$$
so that the sum in $(1)$ converges.

I must be doing something stupid (not for the first or last time) but I can't figure out what.  Please point out my mistake.

Comment: This calculation doesn't take into account the fact that there may be a positive probability that the event never happens. With a coin, this would just be a random walk, which does return.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks.  I knew it had to be something stupid.

Comment: You need to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(6n)!}{(n!)^66^{6n}}$.  If $\lt 1$, it means a positive probability of never happening.  Your estimate is for the average of $n$, when it does happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest why your computation must be wrong (and then point of that what Mark Bennet says is also correct):

Suppose that you found out that for each $6n$, the probability of equal-distribution was even *smaller* --- let's say it's *zero*. (Alternatively, you might ask for the probability that after $6n$ rolls, each number had come up $-3$ times; that probability would *definitely* be zero.

In that case, your sum would look like
$$
\sum_n 6n \cdot 0
$$
which is certainly bounded...but that doesn't mean that the expected number of rolls until we find each face has shown up $-3$ times must be zero, right?

The problem here is that you're computing 
$$
\sum n \cdot p(n)
$$
with the assumption that $\sum p(n) = 1$, i.e., that the even must occur on *some* $n$. But what you're missing is a term that looks like $\infty \cdot p(\infty)$ [informally, of course]: the expected number of rolls before something that never occurs ... actually occurs. :(

Let's look at something very concrete: what's the expected number of rolls you have to make until the total of your rolls is $1$?

Well, $1/6$ of the time, it happens in $1$ roll. What about in 2 rolls, or 3 rolls, or ... ? It never happens. But your sum would be 
$$
1/6 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 2 + 0 \cdot 3 + \ldots
$$
which is nice and finite.